# GitHub Action - Error: Process completed with exit code 14

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using Pylint GitHub action.

Every time I push a new commit all of the builds fail. (except sometimes I get an error like "operation canceled")

This is what my GitHub action file looks like:

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint choam
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pylint-exit](https://github.com/jongracecox/pylint-exit) to determine what that means.

```
pip install pylint-exit
```

If you execute it, you get the following:

```
(exit 14) || pylint-exit $?
The following messages were raised:

  - error message issued
  - warning message issued
  - refactor message issued

No fatal messages detected.  Exiting gracefully...
```

I would assume, it's not really an error